# Password in C checker doesn't seem to work

Tags: c

I am creating a program that requires the user to create a password that has at least one symbol, one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, and a digit. However, I got so many errors. I fixed most of them but there are still a few I can't seem to figure out. It would be easier to just send a screenshot.

[image: Errors]

And here is my code:

```
    #include <stdio.h> 
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <ctype.h> //To use isupper, isalpha, and isdigit

    int main() {

    //Declaring the variables
    
    char userPassword;
    int i; 
    int digit = 0;
    int upper = 0;
    int lower = 0;
    int letter = 0;
    int symbol = 0;

    //User enters password
    printf("Please create a password including at least 1 number, 1 uppercase letter, and one symbol: ");
    scanf(" %c", &userPassword);

    //strlen makes sure password is not less than 8 characters
    if (strlen(userPassword) < 8) {

        printf("INVALID PASSWORD.");

    }

    else {
        
        //A for loop that checks if all the conditions are met
        for (i = 0; i = 20; i++) {

            //Makes sure password has a letter
            if (isalpha(userPassword[i])) {

                letter++;

            }

            //Makes sure password has an uppercase letter
            else if (isupper(userPassword)) {

                upper++;

            }

            //Makes sure password has a lowercase letter
            else if (islower(userPassword)) {

                lower++;

            }

            //Makes sure password has a digit
            else if (isdigit(userPassword)) {

                digit++;

            }

            //Makes sure password has a symbol
            else if (userPassword == '!' || userPassword == '@' || userPassword == '#' || userPassword == '$' || userPassword == '%' || userPassword == '^' || userPassword == '&' || userPassword == '*' || userPassword == '(' || userPassword == ')' || userPassword == '-' || userPassword == '+' || userPassword == '_');

                symbol++;

        }


    }

    //If the password has all of them, it can be created
    if (digit == 0 && upper == 0 && lower == 0 && letter == 0 && symbol == 0) {

        printf("PASSWORD CREATED.");

    }
    
    else {

        printf("INVALID PASSWORD.");

    }

    return 0;

}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Don't post images of the errors — they're unreadable, especially on mobile devices.  Post the text as text.

Comment: No, it's not easier to send a screenshot. We much prefer a copy-paste of the error.

Comment: Also, which part of "You didn't `#include <string.h>` and you should do so" is hard to understand?  The error message says "you should include `<string.h>`", so why don't you try that?

Comment: Just to echo what @JonathanLeffler sir said, please pay heed to the warning / error message - they are there for a reason!

Comment: Furthermore, `userPassword` is a single character, not a string (it can't be passed to string function, and it can't be indexed).

Comment: And how many time do you think `for (i = 0; i = 20; i++)` will loop? All in all it seems like you have cobbled together your program by guessing or copy-pasting from other sources, and then just put it all together and hope it should work. Please take a few steps back, and get a couple of decent beginners books or take a few beginners classes.

Comment: Counting letters, as well as upper and lower case, is really not necessary.  You also only count upper-case letters that are not also letters and only count lower-case letters that are not also letterw — and pretty much by definition, all upper-case letters are letters, and all lower-case letters are letters.  The final test condition should probably be `if (upper == 0 || lower == 0 || digit == 0 || symbol == 0) { /* Not allowed */ } else { /* Allowed */ }`.  Etc.  There are a lot of issues with the code; think carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, we need to address some error in syntax as well as logic. The following things are changed:

1. `userPassword` should be a character array. I assume you have chosen maximum length of password as 20 by looking at your `for` loop. Therefore, declare it as `char userPassword[20]`.
2. The condition in the `for` loop is changed to for `(i = 0; i < 20; i++)`.
3. There was a logical mistake in the algorithm to check the type of the character. Therefore, I have replaced the `else if` constructs to `if`.
4. Character array in C, should be scanned using the `%s` format specifier.
5. Also, don't forget to include **string.h** for the `strlen()` function.

Have a look a the corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h> //To use isupper, isalpha, and isdigit
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    //Declaring the variables
    
    char userPassword[20]; //Assuming maximum length of password is 20.
    int i; 
    int digit = 0;
    int upper = 0;
    int lower = 0;
    int letter = 0;
    int symbol = 0;

    //User enters password
    printf("Please create a password including at least 1 number, 1 uppercase letter, and one symbol: ");
    scanf(" %s", userPassword);

    //strlen makes sure password is not less than 8 characters
    if (strlen(userPassword) < 8) {

        printf("INVALID PASSWORD.");

    }

    else {
        
        //A for loop that checks if all the conditions are met
        for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

            //Makes sure password has a letter
            if (isalpha(userPassword[i])) {

                letter++;

            }

            //Makes sure password has an uppercase letter
            if (isupper(userPassword[i])) {

                upper++;

            }

            //Makes sure password has a lowercase letter
            if (islower(userPassword[i])) {

                lower++;

            }

            //Makes sure password has a digit
            if (isdigit(userPassword[i])) {

                digit++;

            }

            //Makes sure password has a symbol
            if (userPassword[i] == '!' || userPassword[i] == '@' || userPassword[i] == '#' || userPassword[i] == '$' || userPassword[i] == '%' || userPassword[i] == '^' || userPassword[i] == '&' || userPassword[i] == '*' || userPassword[i] == '(' || userPassword[i] == ')' || userPassword[i] == '-' || userPassword[i] == '+' || userPassword[i] == '_'){

                symbol++;
            }

        }
    

        //If the password has all of them, it can be created
        if (digit > 0 && upper > 0 && lower > 0 && letter > 0 && symbol > 0) {

            printf("PASSWORD CREATED.");

        }
        
        else {

            printf("INVALID PASSWORD.");

        }
    }

    return 0;

}
```

**Test Cases:**

1. **Input 1:** Rt%oi45u#

   **Output:** PASSWORD CREATED.
2. **Input 2:** Rt%oiu#

   **Output:** INVALID PASSWORD.

Comment: What's wrong with `ispunct()` for checking for symbols?  Oh, I see — the question doesn't want to allow some bracket-like symbols (`[]{}<>`), and some other punctuation characters (```/~.`=|\;:'"?/.,``` — the code goes across the top of a keyboard).  OK; never mind.  Though `if (strchr("!@#$%^&*()-+_", userPassword[i]) != 0)` might be easier to read.

Comment: The for loop condition is wrong, and will read into likely uninitialized memory.

Comment: I dont think so. The length of declared array is 20.

Comment: It's never initialized, so we assume it contains random data. If the user enters e.g. `password`, you can assume those 20 bytes to contain `password0RËä‹ÆIÏG≠S` (where 0 is a NUL character), which this happily loops over although it should stop at the NUL.

Answer (score 1):

At a quick glance:

- As the warning says, you'll want `#include <string.h>` to include the definition of `strlen`.
- You declare `userPassword`  as only one character, not as an array of characters (e.g. `userPassword[32]`) (which can hold a string up to 31 characters in length).
- You should use `scanf("%s", userPassword)` (or preferably `fgets` with a maximum length) to read strings.
- Your for loop condition is wrong; `for (i = 0; i < strlen(userPassword); i++) {` is likely what you're looking for.
- All but the first `if(isalpha...)` condition are wrong; you're not indexing the password in the rest (`userPassword[i]` c.f. `userPassword`)
- There's an extraneous `;` after the special-character check, so `symbol` gets incremented every time
- The check for whether all of the required character types exist is inverted; it'd create the password when none of the conditions match.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have now. I thought it was rather obvious.

Comment: So did I, but the question came in with the error message saying "You haven't included `<string.h>`" so it wasn't sufficiently obvious to the OP.

Answer (score -3):

Your code have 3 errors.

- You must include string.h for strlen function.
- %c can only cover character. replace %c to %s in  `scanf(" %c", &userPassword);`
- And declare userPassword as char array. replace char userPassword[32]